# Wi-Fi down on Kali Virtual Machines

Tags: command-line, wifi, kali-linux, wlan

On any Kali VM my AWUS036NHA doesn't work because my `wlan0` is always down. No matter what command I use `wlan0` stays down. It looks like I have tried every command. This only affects Kali VMs.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:c6:19:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.217.128/24 brd 192.168.217.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 1718sec preferred_lft 1718sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fec6:19f1/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:18:8f:db:bf:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 00:c0:ca:99:3e:3b
```

Comment: Please don't use Kali as a regular operating system. Don't use it unless you are an expert user and professional penetration tester. Kali ships with networking disabled by default and that's probably what you are seeing, but please, please, please don't try to learn on Kali. See what the Kali devs themselves have to say about this: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ and also some discussion here: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360)

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Before diving into Kali, one really should first read [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs). It's quite comprehensive, and tells you just about everything you need to use it. Among other things that [network services are disabled by default](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/).